# NetBeans FTP "450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost"

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I try to work with NetBeans to log in to my server via FTP the connection was successful.
But while uploading the files I receive an error

```
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for index.php.new
450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (82,180,138,154,139,205).
STOR index.php.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for index.php.new
450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (82,180,138,154,139,167).
STOR index.php.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for index.php.new
450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost
DELE index.php.new
550 index.php.new: No such file or directory
QUIT
221 Goodbye.

Summary
====================
Failed:
file      index.php     450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost
Runtime: 1 s, processed: 0 file(s), 0 K
```

Comment: No clue here, but something gives me the feeling that it's not necessarily an issue with your netbeans installation. 450 is an FTP error code, not a server/client error. That implies to me that the issue is somewhere in configuration (either on your end or the server's end)

Comment: Check the NetBeans log file (**View > IDE Log**) for any additional information that may have been logged for the failed file transfer. Then update your question with the relevant messages, or confirm that nothing was written to the NetBeans log file. Be sure to have that log file open in an Output window after successful connection so that you know exactly which messages (if any) were logged during the failed upload.

Comment: Thanks for your comment
in the log file I not see any error from the FTP only other logs

Comment: @JakobLovern What else can be the error?